# How does this javascript object array work?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to understand something very basic. If I have an object like this:

```
var topics = {}
```

And I do this:

```
topics[name] = ["chapter 1", "chapter 2", "chapter 3"];
```

When I log this object, I don't see the name attribute. What have I done exactly? Have I created a key called name with the value of an array?

Of course I know I can do that by just doing

```
topics.name =  ["chapter 1", "chapter 2", "chapter 3"];
```

But then what is this doing?

```
topics[name] = ["chapter 1", "chapter 2", "chapter 3"];
```

Could someone please clarify?

Comment: This doesn't answer you question but I believe you really want to ask the difference between `topics[name] = ["chapter 1", "chapter 2", "chapter 3"];` and `topics["name"] = ["chapter 1", "chapter 2", "chapter 3"];`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `[]` notation it expects an expression in between, that translates to a string.

Using `name` not enclosed in quotes `'name'` it assumes you are using a variable called name.

Which in your case is `undefined`.

The correct usage would be

```
topics["name"] = ["chapter 1", "chapter 2", "chapter 3"];
```

---

If you want to use a variable you can do things like

```
var prop = 'name';
var topics = {};

topics[prop] = ["chapter 1", "chapter 2", "chapter 3"];
```

this will create the `name` property on the object.. useful for dynamic/automatic creation/filling of objects..

Comment: Does that mean I can assign a function with expressions that evaluate to a string (like a topicName) or a number (like a topicID)?

Comment: @Amit, yes you can do `topics[func()] = '...';` if `func()` returns something that can be converted to string.. (*if that is what you are asking..*)

Answer (score 3):

Your are creating a property on the object with a name based on the value of the `name` variable. If you want to create a property called name in that way you need to do:

```
topics["name"] = ["chapter 1", "chapter 2", "chapter 3"];
```

Answer (score 3):

That should generate an error, unless you have variable `name` defined as a string or a number.

These three are equivalent:

```
var name = "key";
topics[name] = "value";

topics["key"] = "value";

topics.key = "value";
```

Answer (score 2):

There are generally three ways to distinguish:

```
topics.name
topics["name"]
topics[name]
```

The first two are equivalent. So `.xxx` represents the literal key `xxx`, as does `["xxx"]`.

The last one will use whatever the `name` variable contains. E.g.:

```
var name = "test";
topics[name] = 123; // topics["test"] now exists
```

Answer (score 2):

The resulting structure can be seen in the following screen capture.  As stated by mck89, you probably want to use the `"name"` syntax

[image]

Comment: thanks for the comparative screenshots. That made things a lot clear

Comment: Don't use JPEG for screenshots. it makes them all fuzzy.

Comment: @DanD. sorry about that... It usually outputs as a png... I wonder why it didn't that time.

Answer (score 1):

If your code did not result in a `ReferenceError`, you may have already had a variable in global scope named `name`, and created a new property of `name`'s contents.